# Android - How I can show my Images base standard material?

Tags: android, material-design

How I can show my Images base standard material ?

In my `layout` add a `ViewFlipper` for images I need to have a `Material ViewFlipper` . Is any sample (with support library)?

[image]

Comment: A `ViewFlipper` does not have its own UI. It simply animates between its children. What, exactly, is a "material `ViewFlipper`"?

Comment: I need to a thing same viewFliper but I want that to be base material (I don't need to use animation). Thanks

Comment: Ok . How I can show my Images base standard material ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library, 
I am sure you are looking for this.
Let me know if it works for you.
And don't forget to mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider